# Getting access-violation in QueryInterface API

Tags: crash, windbg, access-violation, callstack, mmc

I am getting a crash in MMC code. The dump is pointing to `p->QueryInterface(GetIID(), reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pInterface));`

The disassembly shows as below,

//fill method is called.

```
BSecRem!std::fill<int *,int>:
5d931510 8b442404         mov     eax,[esp+0x4]
5d931514 8b4c2408         mov     ecx,[esp+0x8]
5d931518 3bc1             cmp     eax,ecx
5d93151a 7411             jz   BSecRem!std::fill<int *,int>+0x1d (5d93152d)
5d93151c 8b54240c         mov     edx,[esp+0xc]
5d931520 56               push    esi
5d931521 8b32             mov     esi,[edx]
5d931523 8930             mov     [eax],esi
5d931525 83c004           add     eax,0x4
5d931528 3bc1             cmp     eax,ecx
5d93152a 75f5             jnz  BSecRem!std::fill<int *,int>+0x11 (5d931521)
5d93152c 5e               pop     esi
5d93152d c3               ret
5d93152e cc               int     3
5d93152f cc               int     3
BSecRem!stdext::_Unchecked_move_backward<int *,int *>:
5d931530 8b442408         mov     eax,[esp+0x8]
5d931534 8b542404         mov     edx,[esp+0x4]
5d931538 2bc2             sub     eax,edx
5d93153a c1f802           sar     eax,0x2
5d93153d 56               push    esi
5d93153e 8b742410         mov     esi,[esp+0x10]
5d931542 8d0c8500000000   lea     ecx,[00000000+eax*4]
5d931549 2bf1             sub     esi,ecx
5d93154b 85c0             test    eax,eax
5d93154d 7e0d jle BSecRem!stdext::_Unchecked_move_backward<int *,int *>+0x2c (5d93155c)
5d93154f 51               push    ecx
5d931550 52               push    edx
5d931551 51               push    ecx
5d931552 56               push    esi
5d931553 ff15e034a65d   call dword ptr [BSecRem!_imp__memmove_s (5da634e0)]
5d931559 83c410           add     esp,0x10
5d93155c 8bc6             mov     eax,esi
5d93155e 5e               pop     esi
5d93155f c3               ret
BSecRem!_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<PATENTTEMPOCXLib::_DPatentTempOCX,&_GUID_6042985e_c7cc_4286_b5c4_48a347173739> >::_QueryInterface<IUnknown *>:
5d931560 8b442404         mov     eax,[esp+0x4]
5d931564 56               push    esi
5d931565 8bf1             mov     esi,ecx
5d931567 85c0             test    eax,eax

5d931569 7439 jz instant.dll!_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<PATENTTEMPOCXLib::_DPatentTempOCX,&_GUID_7072787e_ddeb_1223_9aab4_9aab4d923e31> >::_QueryInterface<IUnknown *>+0x44 (5d9315a4)
5d93156b 8b08             mov     ecx,[eax]
5d93156d 53               push    ebx
5d93156e 57               push    edi
5d93156f 8d542410         lea     edx,[esp+0x10]
5d931573 52               push    edx
5d931574 68cc54a65d       push    0x5da654cc
5d931579 50               push    eax
5d93157a 8b01             mov     eax,[ecx]         ds:002b:0000000c=???????
```

The crash is seen frequently. Specially when I navigate from one interface to other interface of MMC.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a call stack, that's disassembly.

Comment: There's probably a `call` instruction followed by a `cmp` instruction on eax prior to the instructions you listed. Looks like that `call` returned a valid pointer which was then dereferenced by `mov ecx,[eax]` at instruction address  5d93156b. The problem is the logic assumes ecx now holds a valid pointer. But it does not. It holds 0xc. That's why you crash on `mov eax,[ecx]`. Can you post a few instructions prior to address 5d931569 to see what's being called? Try `ub 5d931569` in windbg.

Comment: That's unreadable. Try adding these instructions to your original question so that they appear nicely formatted.

Comment: @MarcSherman I have added code in question. Any clue will be of great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set a breakpoint on BSecRem!_com_ptr_t<_com_IIID<PATENTTEMPOCXLib::_DPatentTempOCX,&_GUID_6042985e_c7cc_4286_b5c4_48a347173739> >::_QueryInterface<IUnknown *>+0xd (which should put you at the `push ebx` instruction). Then see what eax and ecx point to with `ln @eax;ln @ecx`. Then use `dt <type> @ecx` where <type> is the type, if any, displayed by `ln @ecx`.  What does `dt <type> @ecx` show for offset zero? IOW, what is the type at offset zero? From the disassembly it should be a pointer. Then try to figure out why offset zero contains 0xc instead of a valid address.